# Unity's rendering statistics window applied to mobile phones

Tags: unity

Unity has the ability to display in game statistics to help developers via the rendering statistics windows. This information shows information such as triangles and verts being rendered, audio level, fps, main and render thread operations time, etc.

I understand the importance of this information yet I'm still struggling to apply it into mobile phones. In this case I want to know how this information can be tied to mobile phones so that I can easily adjust my game to be suitable for low end phones as well as doing the opposite case.

For example, I want to make a big scene for the player, yet I need to keep an eye out on the triangles being drawn, however I don't know a numeric range to keep this triangles in between for the execution of the game.

¿Is there a way to calculate the maximum values that a phone can handle based on the phone's specs? ¿Should I just keep everything at the lowest, sacrificing graphics for better performance? ¿Or should I just do a trial and error on several phones until I find an equilibrium point between graphics and performance?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Btw you have all the answers in your question. According to my experience, that stats window although very help helpful, but it will give you just an idea about experience in mobile device. And you also can set things according to the device specs, you may keep models with heavy shaders off turn on diffuse on low end devices for example.

I also observe sometimes terrain with 250k tris(stats window) running on iphone4 smoothly. It all depends. Well, again, all is my personal experience, its not necessary that everybody will agree with my points.

Comment: Okay so experience should give the insight into this. Instead of pre-calculating I should just go on and make the game. Afterwards tune some things down to improve performance.

Comment: @RonPaul Something like that